# Random number grouped per column value in an Excel table?

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to generate a random number in an Excel table, grouped by one of the column values. In the example table below, each person gets a random number assigned to them. I can't use the RAND() function by itself because that would give each row a random number. How can this be done?

```
╔════════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ PERSON ║ YEAR ║ RANDOM  ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ Bob    ║ 2017 ║ .012345 ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ Alice  ║ 2017 ║ .444444 ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ Jerry  ║ 2018 ║ .272727 ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ Alice  ║ 2018 ║ .444444 ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ Bob    ║ 2018 ║ .012345 ║
╠════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ Alice  ║ 2019 ║ .444444 ║
╚════════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Generate a list of unique names, then associate a random number to those and use `VLOOKUP` to populate the above table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

[image]

The formula used in `C2` translates to:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,RAND(),INDEX($C$1:C1,MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0)))
```

If I could make another suggestion, you would risk duplicates using `RAND()` but if you replace that part for `ROW()` it would always be unique.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you answering so quickly.